# Docker - CTRL+P CTRL+Q

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker on windows 10 Home, so docker uses the virtual machine box.

When I run the container below and want to leave the commnand CTRL + P CTRL + Q does not work.

docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash

Comment: This type of question is probably better suited for the superuser  or serverfault forum

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
docker run -it --detach-keys "ctrl-p" ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Answer (score -3):

it had work.
first `ctrl+P+Q`, perhaps you feel no work,
then `ctrl+c`, 
last `docker ps`,
you will see result.